# index.js is not changing in cordova project?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I am working in a cordova project  , I started to change index.js

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

changes to index.js  not worked , when I  browsed  index.html via google chrome , I checked the code of index.js in devtools the I saw that the file -index.js was not changed and i found the original code generated by cordova!!

whats wrong ????

Comment: which platform did u build? How r u building de project?

Comment: android platform , I build normally cordova build

Comment: if you are building android platform, check for the apk file to see whether the changes are available inside apk

Comment: I have already checked , also not working , but the code in apk file has been changed

Comment: please load your project in github to test

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into a similar problem, until I realized that I edited the file in:

[project_path]/platforms/android/assets/www/js/index.js

That file is auto-generated from the file you should actually edit, which is:

[project_path]/www/js/index.js

Comment: I have already edited this file I found it was changed , But when I browsed  the file in google chrome I found It wasn't changed !!

Comment: Were you able to fix that ? @MohammadAhmadAbdullah