# Why does a Cordova project have identical copies of index.js?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, file, cordova

I included a lot of background information to help you answer this question, however you can skip down to the heading called 'Questions' to skip to the main point.

## Background

I'm new to using Cordova, and I'm new to an existing Cordova project I want to further develop. As a result, when I look at the project files, I am not sure what are choices made by the previous developers and what are choices made automatically by Cordova. I suspect that Cordova generates a lot of files that are not created by the application developers because in my case there are over 7900 files including source code and README's, and the application was previously (to my knowledge at least) developed by only one person.

While many questions could be asked from that perspective, I would like to narrow in on a specific question to avoid being too broad. I've noted that are many files within the path structure called `index.js`.

```
$ find . -name "index.js"
./platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/www/js/index.js
./platforms/android/app/src/main/assets/www/js/index.js
./platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/balanced-match/index.js
./platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/os-tmpdir/index.js
./platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/concat-map/index.js
./platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/properties-parser/index.js
./platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/elementtree/lib/parsers/index.js
./platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/os-homedir/index.js
./platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/xmlbuilder/lib/index.js
./platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/ansi/examples/beep/index.js
./platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/ansi/examples/progress/index.js
./platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/ansi/examples/clear/index.js
./platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/path-is-absolute/index.js
./platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/brace-expansion/index.js
./platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/sax/test/index.js
./platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/android-versions/index.js
./platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/lodash/index.js
./platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-registry-mapper/index.js
./www/js/index.js
./node_modules/objectorarray/index.js
./node_modules/es-abstract/index.js
./node_modules/es-abstract/test/index.js
./node_modules/isexe/index.js
./node_modules/balanced-match/index.js
./node_modules/object-keys/index.js
./node_modules/object-keys/test/index.js
./node_modules/has/src/index.js
./node_modules/has/test/index.js
./node_modules/semver/test/index.js
./node_modules/string.prototype.trim/index.js
./node_modules/string.prototype.trim/test/index.js
./node_modules/cordova-plugin-file/src/blackberry10/index.js
./node_modules/jsonfile/index.js
./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/ensure/index.js
./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/remove/index.js
./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/move/index.js
./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/output/index.js
./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy-sync/index.js
./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/fs/index.js
./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/empty/index.js
./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/index.js
./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/path-exists/index.js
./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/copy/index.js
./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/move-sync/index.js
./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/json/index.js
./node_modules/fs-extra/lib/mkdirs/index.js
./node_modules/concat-map/index.js
./node_modules/elementtree/lib/parsers/index.js
./node_modules/fs.realpath/index.js
./node_modules/plist/index.js
./node_modules/path-key/index.js
./node_modules/xmlbuilder/lib/index.js
./node_modules/ansi/examples/beep/index.js
./node_modules/ansi/examples/progress/index.js
./node_modules/ansi/examples/clear/index.js
./node_modules/cordova-android/node_modules/balanced-match/index.js
./node_modules/cordova-android/node_modules/os-tmpdir/index.js
./node_modules/cordova-android/node_modules/concat-map/index.js
./node_modules/cordova-android/node_modules/properties-parser/index.js
./node_modules/cordova-android/node_modules/elementtree/lib/parsers/index.js
./node_modules/cordova-android/node_modules/os-homedir/index.js
./node_modules/cordova-android/node_modules/xmlbuilder/lib/index.js
./node_modules/cordova-android/node_modules/ansi/examples/beep/index.js
./node_modules/cordova-android/node_modules/ansi/examples/progress/index.js
./node_modules/cordova-android/node_modules/ansi/examples/clear/index.js
./node_modules/cordova-android/node_modules/path-is-absolute/index.js
./node_modules/cordova-android/node_modules/brace-expansion/index.js
./node_modules/cordova-android/node_modules/sax/test/index.js
./node_modules/cordova-android/node_modules/android-versions/index.js
./node_modules/cordova-android/node_modules/lodash/index.js
./node_modules/cordova-android/node_modules/cordova-registry-mapper/index.js
./node_modules/cordova-android/bin/templates/project/assets/www/js/index.js
./node_modules/for-each/index.js
./node_modules/tape/index.js
./node_modules/path-is-absolute/index.js
./node_modules/brace-expansion/index.js
./node_modules/deep-equal/index.js
./node_modules/has-symbols/index.js
./node_modules/has-symbols/test/index.js
./node_modules/shebang-regex/index.js
./node_modules/is-callable/index.js
./node_modules/through/index.js
./node_modules/through/test/index.js
./node_modules/resumer/index.js
./node_modules/resolve/index.js
./node_modules/resolve/test/resolver/dot_main/index.js
./node_modules/resolve/test/resolver/multirepo/packages/package-b/index.js
./node_modules/resolve/test/resolver/multirepo/packages/package-a/index.js
./node_modules/resolve/test/resolver/quux/foo/index.js
./node_modules/resolve/test/resolver/incorrect_main/index.js
./node_modules/resolve/test/resolver/same_names/foo/index.js
./node_modules/resolve/test/resolver/dot_slash_main/index.js
./node_modules/resolve/test/shadowed_core/node_modules/util/index.js
./node_modules/resolve/test/node_path/x/ccc/index.js
./node_modules/resolve/test/node_path/x/aaa/index.js
./node_modules/resolve/test/node_path/y/ccc/index.js
./node_modules/resolve/test/node_path/y/bbb/index.js
./node_modules/resolve/test/module_dir/ymodules/aaa/index.js
./node_modules/resolve/test/module_dir/xmodules/aaa/index.js
./node_modules/resolve/test/precedence/aaa/index.js
./node_modules/resolve/test/dotdot/abc/index.js
./node_modules/resolve/test/dotdot/index.js
./node_modules/function-bind/index.js
./node_modules/function-bind/test/index.js
./node_modules/shebang-command/index.js
./node_modules/minimist/index.js
./node_modules/cordova-plugin-network-information/src/blackberry10/index.js
./node_modules/cross-spawn/index.js
./node_modules/es-to-primitive/index.js
./node_modules/es-to-primitive/test/index.js
./node_modules/strip-bom/index.js
./node_modules/is-date-object/index.js
./node_modules/path-parse/index.js
./node_modules/is-symbol/index.js
./node_modules/is-symbol/test/index.js
./node_modules/base64-js/index.js
./node_modules/node-version-compare/index.js
./node_modules/node-version-compare/test/index.js
./node_modules/universalify/index.js
./node_modules/define-properties/index.js
./node_modules/define-properties/test/index.js
./node_modules/nice-try/src/index.js
./node_modules/defined/index.js
./node_modules/object-inspect/index.js
./node_modules/is-regex/index.js
./plugins/cordova-plugin-file/src/blackberry10/index.js
./plugins/cordova-plugin-network-information/src/blackberry10/index.js
```

It would be extremely broad and impractical to question what each and every one of these identically-named files are for, and some may be inanswerable if their existence depends on design choices of the previous developers of this project. Fortunately, I can be more specific than that. I have an issue to debug, and with a specific search string related to the bug, I was able to find that specific files named `index.js` contained that string.

```
$ grep -ril "<search_string>" .
./platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/www/js/index.js
./platforms/android/app/src/main/assets/www/js/index.js
./www/js/index.js
```

And to clarify further, while not being the only files returned by `grep`, these three `index.js` files were the only files that appeared to be relevant to my bug. I then used `cmp` to compare these three files, and I found that they're mutually identical (not shown since `cmp` by default only prints output when there **is** a difference).

There seems to be [some confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50368428/is-index-js-in-cordova-project-necessary) about the importance of `./www/js/index.js`, but it also seems to be the case that I should prefer to edit `./www/js/index.js` rather than `./platforms/android/app/src/main/assets/www/js/index.js` because `./platforms/android/app/src/main/assets/www/js/index.js` is automatically generated by Cordova according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41320104/index-js-is-not-changing-in-cordova-project). This suggest that `./www/js/index.js` is not automatically generated, although this still leaves open whether `./platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/www/js/index.js` is automatically generated. Given that `build` is in the path of `./platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/www/js/index.js`, I suspect that this is a file automatically generated when the command `cordova build android` is run. This leads me to the suspicion that I should edit `./www/js/index.js` and not the other two of these three files.

## Questions

I'm really asking 3 questions in one post, however since their scope and background are nearly identical I would prefer to keep them together for context.

1. Which of the three `index.js` should be edited in developing an application with Cordova?

   ```
   ./platforms/android/app/build/intermediates/assets/debug/www/js/index.js
   ./platforms/android/app/src/main/assets/www/js/index.js
   ./www/js/index.js
   ```
2. The three `index.js` files mentioned in Question 1 are identical. Why do each of these identical copies exist?
3. There are non-identical files named `index.js` in a Cordova project. Why are they all called the same name if they are non-identical in content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should edit `/www/js/index.js`.

The other two files are created during the build process. A built Cordova app will have all `www` folder contents inside an android app structure, that's why they are inside `/platforms/android/app/src/main/`

The other `index.js` files are there because it's a Node.js pattern

Comment: I've accepted this answer because it answers my question, and I've upvoted it because it is clear and succinct.